# SFDX Snapshot - Worker SnapshotTemplateResolver exception

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, snapshot, pilot, force-org-create

Does anyone know how to fix the issue below?

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "name": "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION",
  "message": "Worker SnapshotTemplateResolver threw an unhandled exception. null",
  "exitCode": 1,
  "commandName": "OrgCreateCommand",
  "stack": "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: Worker SnapshotTemplateResolver threw an unhandled exception. null\n    at HttpApi.getError (.local/sfdx/node_modules/jsforce/lib/http-api.js:250:13)\n    at .local/share/sfdx/node_modules/jsforce/lib/http-api.js:95:22\n    at tryCallOne (.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)\n    at .local/share/sfdx/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15\n    at flush (.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)\nOuter stack:\n    at Function.wrap (.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/@salesforce/core/lib/sfdxError.js:151:27)\n    at OrgCreateCommand.catch (.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/ToolbeltCommand.js:246:46)",
  "warnings": []
}
```

I'm able to create and use the DX snapshots (pilot) only when they are created by the same user.

The error above happens only when creating a snapshot with a different user (same "Salesforce" license). Also, it seems that the required permissions to the "org snapshot" object are OK (Read, Create, Edit, Delete, View All), but it may be related to data access or permission.

**Command**

```
sfdx force:org:create --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.snapshot1.json --json --setdefaultusername --durationdays 1 --setalias "MySnapshot"
```

**Definition file** (project-scratch-def.snapshot1.json)

```
{
  "orgName": "No namespace",
  "namespace": "",
  "snapshot": "snapshot_name"
}
```

Note: Both users are able to list the snapshots by executing `sfdx force:org:snapshot:list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to grant the "Modify all" permission to the "Org Snapshots" object to have it fixed.